# Why is more faster do access a local variable instead a field in the Dalvik VM,

Tags: android, performance

I was reading the notepad tutorial of google and I found that at exercise two:

*"We assign the mNotesCursor field to a local variable at the start of the method. This is done as an optimization of the Android code. Accessing a local variable is much more efficient than accessing a field in the Dalvik VM, so by doing this we make only one access to the field, and five accesses to the local variable, making the routine much more efficient. It is recommended that you use this optimization when possible."*

The code:

```
Cursor c = mNotesCursor;
c.moveToPosition(position);
Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY, c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
```

Why is more faster to access a local variable instead a field?

The notepad tutorial is accessible at: http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex2.html
This part is in the step 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Dianne Hackborn (Android framework engineer): "When accessing a member variable, the compiler will very often need to dereference 'this' and reload the value from memory each time it is access, since the value could have changed since it was last used.  Accessing a local variable in contrast can be done just by using the existing value in a register."  See: [Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/JqPQF1pwrjs).

However, going overboard there would seem to go against other Android performance tips such as avoiding the creation of unnecessary objects. [Link](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation).  Also, later that article, on the use of internal Getters it says, "Without a JIT, direct field access is about 3x faster than invoking a trivial getter. With the JIT (**where direct field access is as cheap as accessing a local**), direct field access is about 7x faster than invoking a trivial getter."